# How to align table header in html tables

Tags: html, css

I tried to create html tables with header.

I added 2 rows but I couldn't figure out how to align to header.

My desired result is like this.

[image]

below is my previous work.

What is wrong point? how can I fix it? if someone has opinion please let me know.

Thanks

```css
td {
padding:5px;
border:solid black 1px;}

table{
border-collapse:collapse;
border:solid black 1px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>header</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I hope this will help you:**

```css
td {
padding:5px;
border:solid black 1px;}

table{
border-collapse:collapse;
border:solid black 1px;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <th rowspan="2">header</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `rowspan="2"` since you want to merge 2 rows.

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">header</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find attached the solution:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"> Header</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```